# Apache Not working in xampp version 3.2.2

Tags: php, html, apache, logging, xampp

When I start the apache server using XAMPP v3.2.2, it comes with an error saying:

```
18:30:18  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 
18:30:18  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
18:30:18  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 
18:30:18  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 
18:30:18  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 
18:30:18  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this 
18:30:18  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

So then I go into the error file bit and it says:

```
[Wed Dec 30 18:12:12.892830 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 11372:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include anID which matches the server name 
[Wed Dec 30 18:12:13.066839 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 11372:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name 
[Wed Dec 30 18:12:13.134845 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11372:tid 512] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.0 configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Wed Dec 30 18:12:13.134845 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11372:tid 512] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39 
[Wed Dec 30 18:12:13.134845 2015] [core:notice] [pid 11372:tid 512] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache' 
[Wed Dec 30 18:12:13.142847 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11372:tid 512] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4144 
[Wed Dec 30 18:12:13.900887 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4144:tid 564] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name 
[Wed Dec 30 18:12:14.074292 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4144:tid 564] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name 
[Wed Dec 30 18:12:14.134295 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4144:tid 564] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I am confused and not sure how to fix it.

Comment: i can see only `warn` and `notice` in logs. That is the whole file ?

Comment: Yeah thats all there is in the "Apache (error.log)" file.

Answer (score 0):

If your skype is turned on - you might exit the program because skype is using port 80

Comment: Skype isn't using the ports 80 or 443. I have made sure that the boxes are unticked in the skype settings

Comment: He's right, Skype does conflict with Xampp, but also you need to make sure that Xampp is installed to folders without spaces in their names; the recommended is installing Xampp directly in C: folder. Did you do that? If you did, I'd uninstall and reinstall Xampp again. Maybe something went wrong in the install process. Are you using Windows 10? If you are, this might be also a problem. There are a lot of bugs on Win 10.

Comment: yes i am using windows 10, Is there a another program I could use, similar to xampp?

Comment: the most recognisable after xampp is wampserver - you may check it.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I've found that Win 10 might have a service running at port 80, something named "World Wide Web Publishing Service". What you need to do is stop this service or change the Apache port, like below:

Try this:

*Method 1. Changing Apache default port:*

- On a text or a code editor open the file httpd.config - it should be located at `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`
- Search for "Listen 80".
- Change 80 to any other port number e.g. – 9080
- Start XAMPP.

To access your localhost, open your browser and type: `localhost:9080/sitefolder/` instead of just `localhost/sitefolder/`

You should be ok then.

If it doesn't work, go over the same process to change the port to 80 again and proceed to Method 2.

*Method 2: Stop World Wide Web Publishing Service.*

Note: Unless you’re running some software that depends on the Microsoft IIS Web Server, you should be fine when stopping it.

To stop this service, you can follow this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBVduJ8xOxk).

Comment: :( It should... Try to restart your pc after doing this stuff.